# Trying to create dynamic pages - no display of content when clicking Link element with dynamic url in Next.js/sanity.io

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

I'm trying to create dynamic pages in Next.js 13 for each product that I'm fetching from sanity.io's backend. The URL changes by clicking on a ProductCard component but I keep on failing in displaying the content that is supposed to be shown. I've tried a lot of things that haven't worked and I think it might be because of the file structure. My components look like this:

```
//ProductCard.js

"use client";
import AddToCartButton from "./AddToCartButton";
import MoreInfoButton from "./MoreInfoButton";
import { client } from "@/sanity/lib/client";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "./ProductCard.module.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const router = usePathname();


  console.log("Product:", product);
  console.log("Product Slug:", product.slug);

  return (
    <>
      <Link href={`/shop/products/${product.slug.current}`}>
        <div
          className={styles.productContainer}
          onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
          onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrlBuilder(client)
              .image(product.image)
              .url()})`,
          }}
        >
          <div
            className={`${styles.productInformationContainer} ${
              shouldShowInfo ? styles.isVisible : styles.isNotVisible
            }`}
          >
            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            <p className={styles.productPrice}>CHF {product.price}</p>
            <div className={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <MoreInfoButton />
              <AddToCartButton />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

the console.logs work. My second component, which is supposed to be the dynamic page, looks like this:

```
// page.js (ProductDetailsPage)

import React from "react";
import { ProductDetails } from "../../../features/ProductDetails";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { client } from "@/sanity/lib/client";
import { groq } from "next-sanity";

export const getProductsAsync = async () => {
  return client.fetch(groq`*[_type == "product"]`);
};

async function ProductDetailsPage() {
  const product = await getProductsAsync();

  return (
    <div>
      <ProductDetails product={product} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetailsPage;


// ProductDetails.js

import React from "react";

export const ProductDetails = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div key={product._id}>{product.name}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

file structure:

```
root
-folder: app
--folder: components
---file: ProductCard.js
--folder: features
---file: ProductDetails.js
--folder: shop
---folder: products
----folder: [slug]
-----file: page.js (ProductDetailsPage)
```

I don't know what to do to be honest and the internet and their documentation also doesn't really help. Furthermore, is there a way to "wrap" the whole app inside of a Context (createContext) that makes the API fetch available to all the pages/components inside of the app/project? or does this happen by default if you fetch inside of the app page.js? For now, i'm fetching the data for every single page/component that needs it individually and i would assume that's not how it's intended to work. I've tried wrapping the app page.js inside of a context but only got errors. Thanks for your help!